# Creating multiple .txt files while restricting size of each

Tags: vb.net, io, streamwriter

In my program, I collect bits of information on a massive scale, hundreds of thousands to millions of lines each. I am trying to limit each file I create to a certain size in order to be able to quickly open it and read the data. I am using a HashSet to collect all the data without duplicates.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
Dim Founds As HashSet(Of String)
Dim filename As String = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\Sorted_byKING\sorted" + Label4.Text + ".txt")
Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
    For Each line As String In Founds
        writer.WriteLine(line)
    Next
    Label4.Text = Label4.Text + 1   'Increments sorted1.txt, sorted2.txt etc
End Using
```

**So, my question is:**

How do I go about saving, let's say 250,000 lines in a text file before moving to another one and adding the next 250,000?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use Labels to simply store values. You should use variables instead, that's what variables are for.

Another advice, always use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_) to concatenate paths, that way you don't have to worry about if each part of the path ends with a separator character or not.

**Now, to answer your question:**

If you'd like to insert the text line by line, you can use something like:

```
Sub SplitAndWriteLineByLine()
    Dim Founds As HashSet(Of String) 'Don't forget to initialize and fill your HashSet
    Dim maxLinesPerFile As Integer = 250000

    Dim fileNum As Integer = 0
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty

    Dim writer As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing

    For Each line As String In Founds
        If counter Mod maxLinesPerFile = 0 Then
            fileNum += 1
            filename = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                                       $"Sorted_byKING\sorted{fileNum.ToString}.txt")
            If writer IsNot Nothing Then writer.Close()
            writer = New IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        End If
        writer.WriteLine(line)
        counter += 1
    Next
    writer.Dispose()
End Sub
```

However, if you will be inserting the text *from the HashSet* as is, you probably don't need to write line by line, instead you can write each "bunch" of lines at once. You could use something like the following:

```
Sub SplitAndWriteAll()
    Dim Founds As HashSet(Of String) 'Don't forget to initialize and fill your HashSet
    Dim maxLinesPerFile As Integer = 250000

    Dim fileNum As Integer = 0
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty
    For i = 0 To Founds.Count - 1 Step maxLinesPerFile
        fileNum += 1
        filename = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                                   $"Sorted_byKING\sorted{fileNum.ToString}.txt")
        IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, Founds.Skip(i).Take(maxLinesPerFile))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Testing the second one out in just a min. Thank you so much though these both look amazing